# Where to download PyBOMBS and how to install this package on CentOS6.x?

Tags: python

Using "pip" can automatically download and install PyBOMBS. However, my operating system is CentOS6.x (which is "yum"). In this case, where could I download PyBOMBS?

Besides, I have easy_install in my system. Could this help with the installation of PyBOMBS after being downloaded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

pip is the Python package manager; it has nothing to do with your OS.

Install pip [according to the instructions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/), then do `pip install pybombs`.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the link to "get-pip.py". What should be the command for "git clone" in order to download this package?

Comment: No need to clone it via git; the link there takes you to the actual script which you can download and run.